# In a Pandas Dataframe Groupby.agg() to combine mulitple columns as arguments to a lambda function

Tags: dataframe, lambda, aggregate, pandas-groupby, multiple-columns

I want to be able to create an aggregate groupby column that is created from an aggregate function that depends on more than just one column of the original dataframe. For example (in this case), I want to compute the exponentially weighted mean of a list of assets with a given half life.

Here is an example where I compute the mean and std from the built in functions and the mean from a lambda function ...

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['2019-11-30','2019-10-31', '2019-09-30', '2019-08-31', '2019-07-31', '2019-06-30',
                            '2019-11-30','2019-10-31', '2019-09-30', '2019-08-31', '2019-07-31', '2019-06-30',
                            '2019-11-30','2019-10-31', '2019-09-30', '2019-08-31', '2019-07-31', '2019-06-30'
                           ],
                    'ASSET': ['ASSET1', 'ASSET1', 'ASSET1', 'ASSET1', 'ASSET1', 'ASSET1',
                              'ASSET2', 'ASSET2', 'ASSET2', 'ASSET2', 'ASSET2', 'ASSET2',
                              'ASSET3', 'ASSET3', 'ASSET3', 'ASSET3', 'ASSET3', 'ASSET3'
                             ],
                   'MARKET_VALUE': [10] * 6 + [15] * 6 + [20] * 6 + np.random.randint(-50,50,18,)/100
                   }
                )

df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
df['RANK'] = df.groupby('ASSET')['DATE'].rank(ascending=False) - 1
df = df.sort_values(by=['ASSET', 'RANK'])

print(df)

         DATE   ASSET  MARKET_VALUE  RANK
0  2019-11-30  ASSET1          9.94   0.0
1  2019-10-31  ASSET1          9.97   1.0
2  2019-09-30  ASSET1         10.14   2.0
3  2019-08-31  ASSET1         10.17   3.0
4  2019-07-31  ASSET1         10.17   4.0
5  2019-06-30  ASSET1          9.59   5.0
6  2019-11-30  ASSET2         15.33   0.0
7  2019-10-31  ASSET2         14.71   1.0
8  2019-09-30  ASSET2         14.86   2.0
9  2019-08-31  ASSET2         15.37   3.0
10 2019-07-31  ASSET2         15.20   4.0
11 2019-06-30  ASSET2         15.38   5.0
12 2019-11-30  ASSET3         20.38   0.0
13 2019-10-31  ASSET3         19.62   1.0
14 2019-09-30  ASSET3         20.08   2.0
15 2019-08-31  ASSET3         20.15   3.0
16 2019-07-31  ASSET3         19.89   4.0
17 2019-06-30  ASSET3         20.37   5.0

stats = df.groupby('ASSET').agg({'MARKET_VALUE': {'count': 'count',
                                                  'mean': 'mean',
                                                  'std': 'std',
                                                  'meanLambda': (lambda x: x.sum() / x.count()),
                                                  }
                                 }

                                )

print(stats)

stats
       MARKET_VALUE                                
              count       mean       std meanLambda
ASSET                                              
ASSET1            6   9.996667  0.223577   9.996667
ASSET2            6  15.141667  0.287570  15.14167
ASSET3            6  20.081667  0.292124  20.081667
```

Now I want to try to add another lambda function that uses the 'RANK' column as well as the 'MARKET_VALUE' column ...

```
halflife = 6
k = math.log(.5) / halflife
stats = df.groupby('ASSET').agg({'MARKET_VALUE': {'count': 'count',
                                                  'mean': 'mean',
                                                  'std': 'std',
                                                  'mean2': (lambda x: x.sum() / x.count()),
                                                  'ewm': (lambda x: (np.exp(k * df['RANK']) * x).sum())/(np.exp(k * df['RANK'])).sum()
                                                  }
                                 }

                                )
```

But I get an error because we only have access to x, the 'MARKET_VALUE' column.

I did manage to successfully compute it as a single column as follows ...

```
stats2 = df.groupby('ASSET').agg(lambda x: (np.exp(k * x['RANK']) * x['MARKET_VALUE']).sum() / np.exp(k * x['RANK']).sum())
```

But is gives the same values for multiple columns:

```
stats2
             DATE  MARKET_VALUE       RANK
ASSET                                     
ASSET1  10.004711     10.004711  10.004711
ASSET2  15.122501     15.122501  15.122501
ASSET3  20.076236     20.076236  20.076236
```

And if I try to combine more than one of these I get a key error:

```
stats3 = df.groupby('ASSET').agg([lambda x: x['MARKET_VALUE'].count(),lambda x: (np.exp(k * x['RANK']) * x['MARKET_VALUE']).sum() / np.exp(k * x['RANK']).sum()])


 File "C:\Users\p814635\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'MARKET_VALUE'
```

So in general I want access to any column in the agg lambda function (which only returns one column) and the ability to have multiple functions (like meanLambda and stdLambda and maybe other stats) and which each return one column for each statistic per function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach on `stats2` is close. Try to use `apply` instead of `agg`. Then assign it back to the columns `'ewm'` of `stats` to combine the result.

```py
stats2 = df.groupby('ASSET').apply(lambda x: (np.exp(k * x['RANK']) * x['MARKET_VALUE']).sum() / np.exp(k * x['RANK']).sum())
stats['ewm'] = stats2

       MARKET_VALUE                                        ewm
              count       mean       std      mean2           
ASSET                                                         
ASSET1            6   9.996667  0.223577   9.996667  10.004711
ASSET2            6  15.141667  0.287570  15.141667  15.122501
ASSET3            6  20.081667  0.292124  20.081667  20.076236
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It worked well. I also inserted the line `stats.columns = stats.columns.droplevel()` before so that the column indexing would be consistent with the other columns. Cheers ...